# Word.SpellingSuggestions throws Cannot find proofing tools

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-interop

Running this code:

```
_app = new Word.Application();
Word.SpellingSuggestions listOfSuggestions = _app.GetSpellingSuggestions(theWord, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, "Spanish (Mexico)");
```

Throws this Exception: Cannot find proofing tools for

- I use Word Object library 12  (Should be Word 2007)
- Leaving out the MainDictionary parameter doesn't make any difference
- Specifying wdMexicanSpanish doesn't work either
- Spell checking works perfectly for English and Spanish in Word itself.

What could be wrong?